# Pass dynamic CPU resources to create kubernate in java

Tags: java, maven, kubernetes

Am using **io.kubernetes** to create dynamic kubernate pods from java.

I wanted to set the resources using **KubernetesConstants** class as shown in bellow

**Jave Code:**

```
        Map<String, Quantity> requests = new HashMap<>();
        requests.put("memorey", Quantity.fromString(Long.toString(128)));
        requests.put("cpu", Quantity.fromString(Long.toString(1)));
        V1ResourceRequirements resourceRequirements =new V1ResourceRequirements();
        resourceRequirements.setRequests(requests);
        Map<String, Quantity> limits = new HashMap<>();
        limits.put("memory", Quantity.fromString(Long.toString(512)));
        limits.put("cpu", Quantity.fromString(Long.toString(1)));
        resourceRequirements.setLimits(limits);
        container.setResources(resourceRequirements);
```

Can someone help me how set CPU resources as 300m as shown bellow in yaml file

**yaml file :**

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: "1"
  requests:
    cpu: 500m
```

**maven dependency:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-beta1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Quantity.fromString("300m")`. *Extra text to be long enough.*